# How to access and work with XML from API in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, api

My goal is to pull XML data from the API and load it to a sql server database. The first step I'm attempting here is to access the data and display it. Once I get this to work I'll loop through each row and insert the values into a sql server database. When I try to run the code below nothing happens and when I paste the url directly into the browser I get this error

```
"2010-03-08 04:24:17 Wallet exhausted: retry after 2010-03-08 05:23:58. 2010-03-08 05:23:58"
```

To me it seems that every iteration of the foreach loop makes a call to the site and I get blocked for an hour.  Am I retrieving data from the API in an incorrect manner? Is there some way to load the data into memory or an array then loop through that?

Here's the bit of code I hacked together.

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Xml;
using System.Data;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string userID = "123";
            string apiKey = "abc456";
            string characterID = "789";
            string url = "http://api.eve-online.com/char/WalletTransactions.xml.aspx?userID=" + userID + "&apiKey=" + apiKey + "&characterID=" + characterID;
            XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmldoc.Load(url);
            XmlNamespaceManager xnm1 = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmldoc.NameTable);
            XmlNodeList nList1 = xmldoc.SelectNodes("result/rowset/row", xnm1);
            foreach (XmlNode xNode in nList1)
            {
                Response.Write(xNode.InnerXml + "<br />");
            }
        }

        catch (SqlException em)
        {
            Response.Write(em.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a sample of the xml

```
<eveapi version="2"> 
  <currentTime>2010-03-06 17:38:35</currentTime> 
  <result> 
    <rowset name="transactions" key="transactionID" columns="transactionDateTime,transactionID,quantity,typeName,typeID,price,clientID,clientName,stationID,stationName,transactionType,transactionFor"> 
      <row transactionDateTime="2010-03-06 17:16:00" transactionID="1343566007" quantity="1" typeName="Co-Processor II" typeID="3888" price="1122999.00" clientID="1404318579" clientName="unseenstrike" stationID="60011572" stationName="Osmeden IX - Moon 6 - University of Caille School" transactionType="sell" transactionFor="personal" /> 
      <row transactionDateTime="2010-03-06 17:15:00" transactionID="1343565894" quantity="1" typeName="Co-Processor II" typeID="3888" price="1150000.00" clientID="1404318579" clientName="unseenstrike" stationID="60011572" stationName="Osmeden IX - Moon 6 - University of Caille School" transactionType="sell" transactionFor="personal" /> 
    </rowset> 
  </result> 
  <cachedUntil>2010-03-06 17:53:35</cachedUntil> 
</eveapi>
```

Comment: This question is specific to the particular API. Only someone who knows about this specific API could tell you why it behaves that way.

Comment: Eve does have a developer forum and I'll post this question there also, but I figured this was more of a general programming question on how to properly work with XML data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some quick searching (google) shows that [this is the EVE API cache mechanism kicking in](http://www.eve-search.com/thread/1263311/page/1). If you query the same data from the same key and IP, it tells you to re-use what you already have. So make sure you write any results you *do* get to disk or database *straight away*. Some cache times are 1 day...

Comment: So how do I go about doing that? Should I use the method described in the post below (WebClient class and its DownloadFile method) or are there other ways to store the data before I insert it into a database?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576534/how-to-read-xml-data-from-a-url-by-using-vb-net-and-save/1576729#1576729

Answer (score 1):

@Jarek
 You could just store the xml file as a local cache to your webservers file structure like .../Users/thisusersid/mycustomfile_02102011.xml, then when the user logs in again just pull the file, split the file name, check the dates and use the most recent file as the default. Then you can allow the user to update their data from the eveapi manually by clicking a button/link to retrieve the latest & greatest.